# How to sort a list by another list

Tags: list, sorting, flutter, dart

How can I sort a list with objects so that the properties of the objects match a different list in dart?

```dart
class Example {
  String _id;
  String get id => _id;
}

List examples = [Example(id: 'hey'), Example(id: 'foo'), Example(id: 'baa')]
List ids = ['foo', 'baa', 'hey']

print(examples.sortBy(ids)) ???????


OUTPUT:

  [Example(id: 'foo'), Example(id: 'baa'), Example(id: 'hey')]
```

Comment: Instead of sorting, you can map a list of `ids` to a list of `Examples`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't the most performant way, but it's probably one of the simplest. Use a sorting method that sorts based on the object's field's location in the other array:

```dart
final sortedExamples = List.from(examples)
  ..sort((a, b) => ids.indexOf(a.id) - ids.indexOf(b.id));
```

This way is slightly more involved but more performant as you only need to iterate over each list once each. It involves making a map out of your list and then using that as the source of truth to rebuild a sorted list:

```dart
final ref = Map.fromIterable(examples, key: (e) => e.id, value: (e) => e);
final sortedExamples = List.from(ids.map((id) => ref[id]));
```

The first option is better if space is an issue, the second is better if speed is an issue.

Comment: Amazing! I learn something new everyday from @Abion47's answers.